# Bigquery joining problems

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using bigquery quite successfully and are today storing massive amount of game events (ca 100 millions per day).

These events are then process daily in order to generate daily KPI's.

Now to my problem ...

We are in the phase of adding support for AB testing. I.e. we divide users into different groups to be able to compare how different versions of our games perform.

Our initial approach was to locate all users that has joined a certain group and then make a join.

But now we get an error when using unions in the subselect.

This SQL works  ...

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(ts), "%Y-%m-%d") time, 4 as appId, locale, platform, "all" as version, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as count 

FROM (SELECT ts,userId,locale,eventId 

    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ts,userId,locale,eventId 
        FROM 
            [analytics_davinci_gunnar.events_app4_v4_201312]
    ) a

    INNER JOIN EACH (
        SELECT userId
        FROM
            [analytics_davinci_gunnar.events_app4_v4_201312]
        WHERE 
            eventId = 1600 and abName = 'foo' and abVersion = 0 AND abCase = 3
    ) b

   ON a.userId = b.userId
)

WHERE DATE(ts) >= "2013-08-02" AND DATE(ts) <= "2014-01-28"

GROUP BY time, locale

ORDER BY time DESC, count DESC
```

This SQL using unions fails.
Query Failed
Error: ** Unexpected. Please try again**.

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(ts), "%Y-%m-%d") time, 4 as appId, locale, platform, "all" as version, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as count 

FROM (SELECT ts,userId,locale,eventId 

    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ts,userId,locale,eventId 
        FROM 
            [analytics_davinci_gunnar.events_app4_v4_201311],
            [analytics_davinci_gunnar.events_app4_v4_201312]
    ) a

    INNER JOIN EACH (
        SELECT userId
        FROM
            [analytics_davinci_gunnar.events_app4_v4_201312]
        WHERE 
            eventId = 1600 and abName = 'foo' and abVersion = 0 AND abCase = 3
    ) b

   ON a.userId = b.userId
)

WHERE DATE(ts) >= "2013-08-02" AND DATE(ts) <= "2014-01-28"

GROUP BY time, locale

ORDER BY time DESC, count DESC
```

Comment: Looking into this - for these errors please include the jobid for faster debugging!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in BigQuery that we believe we have fixed. Please file a new bug at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list if you still see the problem.

Comment: Ok I Will test this next week. We coded around this by adding active abtests to all events.